# SELECT with lower case + unaccent + multiple columns in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Table **schools**

```
id | address                 | name
1  | Rybničná 59, Bratislava | Stredná odborná škola elektrotechnická
2  | Ul. Sibírska 1, Trnava  | Stredná odborná škola elektrotechnická
```

## What I want

From client If I want to type:

1. Stredná odborná
2. stredná odborná
3. stredna odborna

It must find rows with id 1 and 2

If I want to type Bratislava or bratis It must find row with id 1

### What I have

```
SELECT * FROM schools WHERE unaccent(address) LIKE ('%' || 'bratis' || '%');
```

I need to select from 2 columns (address and name)

Comment: This is to do with encoding; Poke the database and see if you can reassign the database encoding using `UPDATE pg_database set encoding = pg_char_to_encoding('UTF8') where datname = 'thedb'`

Answer (score 1):

To make the search [case insentive](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html), use `ILIKE` instead of `LIKE`. Then, you would want to remove the accents from the input string as well. At last, just use `AND` or `OR` to combine the two criteria (note that you could use the same search term for both columns - use `OR` in this case)

```
SELECT * FROM schools 
WHERE unaccent(address) ILIKE ('%' || unaccent('bratis') || '%')
  AND unaccent(name) ILIKE ('%' || unaccent('Stredná odborná') || '%')
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this works

```
  SELECT * FROM schools 
  WHERE unaccent(address|| ' ' ||name) ILIKE ('%' || 'bratis' || '%');
```